2000s horror film where crime scene photographer raises ghost
I'm looking for the title of an early 2000s horror movie. It was definitely in English and most likely American.
I don't remember much about it except that it revolves around this guy, he's crime scene photographer for a magazine. He takes photos of some gruesome accidents. For some reason, he goes to a graveyard where he disturbs a woman's tombstone. He kicks it out of the ground and cuts his own thumb to smear blood on it. He takes a photo but he's disturbed the spirit of the woman who that grave belonged to. She starts haunting him. Towards the end he's surrounded by a a bunch of ghosts/zombies that supposedly kill him I think. The very ending is of a girl looking at his photographs. 

Hi! Do you remember the country\language?

Hey - it was definitely English and most likely American

Sounds like The Night Flier from 1997, which was based on a short Stephen King story.

Richard Dees [Miguel Ferrer], a cynical reporter for the sleazy tabloid weekly Inside View, is assigned to investigate a series of "vampire" murders, committed at isolated rural air strips. The gruesome trail takes him on a journey into the bowels of hell.

He photographs crime scenes and at one point cuts his finger and smears blood on a tombstone. Near the end, he's attacked by an undead horde. Here's the trailer:


 

Ahh yes this is it - I was 6 when this came out so I only remembered a few details. Thanks so much!
